# Undefined control sequence: \ResetDatamodelConstraints in biblatex 3.x

Tags: biblatex

I have the following minimal working example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dbx}  
    \ResetDatamodelEntrytypes
    \ResetDatamodelFields
    \ResetDatamodelEntryfields
    \ResetDatamodelConstraints
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example.
\end{document}
```

Compiling using the latest update of texlive (pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17, biblatex 3.7) in my environment throws the following error:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def) (./test.dbx
! Undefined control sequence.
\ResetDatamodelConstraints ...tamodel@constraints 
                                                  \@empty 
l.9 \ResetDatamodelConstraints

?
```

The code I extracted this example from worked before updating my tex environment.  In the current [biblatex documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) the command `\ResetDatamodelConstraints` is still defined. Looking in [blx-dm.def](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/blx-dm.def) one may also find the commands definition.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a typo, specifically a missing `\`, in `blx-dm.def`. The issue is known and was fixed on Github a few weeks ago (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/8d90d5c4897a8316de5f51fce7810c12a75846a8). The version with the fix (3.8) has not been released yet, though.

In the meantime it should be enough to add

```
  \renewrobustcmd*{\ResetDatamodelConstraints}{%
    \global\let\blx@bcf@datamodel@constraints\@empty}
```

to your `.dbx`.